# Как загрузить файл на сервер через Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Доброго времени суток,

Пишу Telegram Bot используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI.
Нужно отправить файл на сервер, и вытянуть из него данные.
Подскажите, как загрузить текстовый файл на сервер через Telegram Bot?

Comment: Где находится файл? Что за сервер? Причём тут Telegram? Какие данные нужно вытянуть?

Comment: Юзер будет загружать файл в телеграм бот, и мне нужен метод библиотеки pyTelegramBotAPI, который захватит файл на сервере.